# Access 2016 SQL Join Two Queries - invalid procedure call

Tags: sql, join, append, union, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to join two Access queries (qry_Table1 and qry_Table2) using SQL via a UNION command as a third query, but I get the following error message:

[image: Access Error Message]

The UNION command to join the two queries (as an append), each having the same columns:

```
SELECT  CustomerNumber

FROM qry_Table_1

UNION SELECT CustomerNumber

FROM qry_Table_2;
```

I know that the issue comes from CustomerNumber in qry_Table2, because I can join any or all of the rest of the columns (not shown here) if I exclude this.

qry_Table1:

```
SELECT CustomerNumber FROM Customer;
```

qry_Table2:

```
SELECT Left("88800000",8-Len([Customer2].CustomerNumber)) & [Customer2].CustomerNumber AS CustomerNumber FROM Customer2;
```

(The above SELECT statement pads the start of the customer number up to 8 digits using the "88800000" string and works fine within qry_Table2.)

Both qry_Table1 and qry_Table2 have the same columns, the only difference being that qry_Table2 has the CustomerNumber column replaced with the calculated one as per the above.

I'm not sure if this is an Access issue, or an issue with how I've layered the queries.

Obviously I've stripped all the rest of the queries out as they are sensitive and not relevant.

Can anybody offer me any advice on where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!!!

Phil.

Comment: I can't test at the moment but is it because one is returning a number and the other a string? What if you use Cstr([CustomerNumber]) in the first query?

Comment: Hi Minty, thanks for responding and apologies for the slow reply - I'd given up on this! In the end, I decided it was more efficient to do this conversion in the source data as a secondary ID column rather than having to do it on the fly with SQL.